# Custom Grid axis labels, to only display decimal minutes ignoring degrees

Tags: qgis

I have created a chart with a very small grid, I would like the axis labels to only display the decimal minute value, so I have more space to increase font size, by removing the degree value.
I presume I need to use the custom format, but I can't work out the coding.

Picture of my current axis labels at the moment. [image]

other example of how I would like to display the asix labels [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can customize how the coordinates are printed.

Select a `custom` format, then click the epsilon button to the right and enter the following code.

```
lpad(round((abs( @grid_number)*3600 % 60)%60,2),2,'0')
```

So it take the decimal degree grid coordinate (`@grid_number`), get rid of the sign (`abs`), multiply by 60*60=3600 to get an integer number of seconds. Then it computes the modulo (`%`) to get the number of minutes, and from that again to get the number of seconds. It rounds to 2 decimals (that's really up to you, it could even be 0 here) and at last it pads the computed values with 0's to the left (`lpad`) so that 5 seconds is displayed as 05

PS: For illustration purposes, the map behind shows the computed value and the full DMS coordinate.
[image]

**EDIT** If you want decimal minutes instead of degrees-minutes-seconds, the formula is simpler. To display just the decimals, without any transformation, you can just manipulate the textual representation of the coordinate:

```
left(right(to_dm(  @grid_number , @grid_axis ,3),5),4)
```

It prints the coordinate in degree-minutes, with 3 decimals. It then taks the rightmost 5 charters (`.123'`) and then the 4 left most ones (`.123`)

Comment: Hello Thanks for you reply, that's not quite what I'm looking to do though. 
My axis labels are in Degree's, decimal Minutes (dd; mm.mmm) I would like to only display the minutes value (mm.mmm) and ignore the degrees. Do you know if this is possible? Currently it would read 49' 12.820' I would like it to only show 12.820' or even just  .820'

Comment: @PhilJersey see edits for decimal minutes. Note that your picture of intended result and comment don't match, you can play with the multiplication / rounding to display `820` or `.820`

Comment: Thanks again, that's almost what I am trying to achieve. However where the minutes increase and the axis display (for example) 49; 13.010' this only display as 10 Ideally I would like it to appear as .010' for clarity. 
In brief just want the decimals of a minute displayed on the grid axis. I can make a second grid to display the full co-ordinate when the minute value itself increase.

Comment: add the `lpad` from the 1st solution

Comment: lpad(round((abs( @grid_number)*60) 1%*1000)'0')  Tried this but doesn't seem to work

Comment: @PhilJersey see edits